# whitecards (lowercase) skips other players in PlayerVector but the first - why?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have tried for several days to find a solution to this but I am at a loss.

I am creating a Cards Against Humanity game that makes use of a Player class. This player class has functions to add white cards, retrieve a white card, get rid of a white card, get name, set name, and others.

The program goes:

1. Main menu (goes to gameplay, how to play, credits, and quit)
2. Chooses number of players.
3. Creates vector of players
4. Sets player names.
5. Assigns eight cards to each player's whitecards vector.
6. Begins game.

The main issue I have is with the assigning eight cards to each player's whitecards vector.

This is the code for the part of the program that distributes cards.

```
for (i = 0; i < playercount; i++) /* Adds eight white cards to each player's vector of cards */
        {
            PlayerVector.at(i).addwhitecard();
            PlayerVector.at(i).addwhitecard();
            PlayerVector.at(i).addwhitecard();
            PlayerVector.at(i).addwhitecard();
            PlayerVector.at(i).addwhitecard();
            PlayerVector.at(i).addwhitecard();
            PlayerVector.at(i).addwhitecard();
            PlayerVector.at(i).addwhitecard();
        }
```

This is the section of Player.cpp that assigns a white card.

```
bool Player::addwhitecard()`{

whitecard_ptr = fopen("WhiteCards.txt", "r");
if (whitecard_ptr != NULL)
{
    std::cout << "This Part Worked" << std::endl;
    if (maxwhitecardcount >= whitecards.size())
    {
        std::cout << "Yes Continue Pls" << std::endl;
        srand(time(0));
        randomnumber = rand() % 398;
        randomnumber2 = rand() % 398;
        randomnumber3 = rand() % 398;
        randomnumber4 = rand() % 398;
        randomnumber5 = rand() % 398;
        randomnumber6 = rand() % 398;
        randomnumber7 = rand() % 398;
        randomnumber8 = rand() % 398;
        while (getline(WhiteCards, line))
        {
            ++LineNo;
            if (LineNo == randomnumber || LineNo == randomnumber2 || LineNo == randomnumber3 || LineNo == randomnumber4 || LineNo == randomnumber5 || LineNo == randomnumber6 || LineNo == randomnumber7 || LineNo == randomnumber8)
            {
                whitecards.push_back(line);
                std::cout << "Yes! This size is: " << whitecards.size() << std::endl;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << name << "has too many white cards!";
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

This is the constructor for the player class.

```
    Player::Player(std::string name, int points)
   {
       this->points = 0;
       this->name = "PlayerName";
       this->whitecards;
   }
```

And this is the player class itself in the header file

```
    class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    Player(std::string name, int points);
    void drawwhitecard();
    std::string getwhitecard();
    void ridwhitecard();
    void addpoint();
    int getpoints();
    bool addwhitecard();
    void namechar();
    bool showwhitecards();
    bool setname();
    std::string getname();
protected:
    int points;
    std::vector<std::string> whitecards;
    std::string name;
    int whitecardcount;
    int maxwhitecardcount = 8;
    int whitecardchoicenumber = 0;
};
```

I tried to put the whitecards vector as an argument in player, but I wasn't able to use the vector in the arguments list when creating a player object in the main code.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong? Whether I do actually need to put the vector in the arguments and how to use it in an arguments list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? "I wasn't able to use the vector" doesn't give us a good idea.

Comment: @A115,  May the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) be with you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When I put vector in the list of arguments for the player class, I wasn't able to call it when creating an instance of player in the main code. I was able to set name to "Player", set the score to 0, but I wasn't able to set the vector to any value.

Comment: Again with the "I wasn't able". What do you mean by that? What happened when you tried, exactly?

Comment: Using a debugger will help provide the StackOveflow community with information about your issue.  Please use a debugger and edit your post with information about your debugging session.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit An error comes up - "type name is not allowed" whenever I try to put std::vector<std::string> whitecards in the list of arguments when creating an instance of player. I'm not sure if I should be including the vector in the arguments list to begin with. But when I tried to in order to find a solution, it returned the error. Even when I created a std::vector<std::string> in the source.cpp and put it in the list so it recognises there is a vector of the same type, the same problem still occurred (only one player gets eight cards, the rest get none).

Comment: You need please to present a [MCVE], and describe the problem clearly and concisely, with evidence, in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, though it's somewhat long.

I had to add 56 other randomnumber variables that all the other players can use.

Sorry I couldn't provide a MCVE due to time constraints.